# Best suitable Machine Learning algorithm for classifying bank transactions

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I am new to field of Machine Learning so I hope that there a people here to help me with my case...

I want to apply Machine Learning to bank transactions in order to determine if a particular transacties belongs to grocery, assurance, mortgage etc.

A typical transactions looks something like below:

```
accountnumber | counterpart accountnumber | amount | type | code | date | time | description
12345678 | 09876543 | 100.00 | c | bg | 01-02-2001 | 10:01:22 | Hema hermanruiterstraat pasnr:78 10:01:22
12345678 | 12343278 | 45.95 | d | ba | 02-02-2001 | 18:34:54 | Albert Hein janvangalenstraar
```

I looked at Naive Bayes classifiers but I am not very pleased with the results I got. I trained my model based on 5 attributes

- amount
- type (c = 1, d = 2)
- code (bg = 1, ba = 2)
- date (converted to long)
- time (converted to long)

My question is which algorithm would be best to classify these transactions? If possible please provide some background about the algorithm of choice.

cheers!
Martijn

Comment: You should split the date and time features into multiple binary features, e.g. `happened between 1pm and 2pm (true/false)`. Your naive bayes classifier can probably not handle long values correctly.

Comment: I changed the date & time to multiple features...stil not satified with results. I changed the date to day of the week like monday = 1 etc and time to morning = 1, afternoon = 2, evening = 3 and night = 4.

Comment: I would think the amount would be the most important feature. Nobody gets a $46 mortgage, or a $500K shopping bill. Some kind of decision tree might be enough, it would simply have to split the very numbers from the very large numbers from the small ones. If it's combinations of features that determine it perhaps a Random Forest would work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, can you give some insights?